# Why does this new window notification appear only when the user has manually pressed a button in a chromedriver instance? Selenium related

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, window-handles

I have a simple python program that opens [this page](https://opensea.io/) with `chromedriver.exe`, then it clicks on the wallet icon located at the top right corner of that page, for then clicking on the MetaMask wallet button, here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data') #Add the user data path as an argument in selenium Options
opt.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default") #Add the profile directory as an argument in selenium Options
s = Service(r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe') #Use the chrome driver located at the corresponding path  

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) #execute the chromedriver.exe with the previous conditions
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://opensea.io/') #go to the opensea main page.

initial_page = driver.current_window_handle  #make the previous page the current one
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button'))) #wait for the wallet button to be enabled for clicking
wallet_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button')
wallet_button.click() #click that wallet button
#time.sleep(1)
wallet_options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-testid='WalletSidebar--body']//li")
for i in wallet_options:
    if "MetaMask" in i.get_attribute('innerText'): #find the MetaMask wallet button
        i.click() #click the MetaMask wallet button
```

The problem I noticed when testing this program was that after clicking the MetaMask wallet button via automation, the expected `Metamask Notification` window was never displayed, and the current window kept loading that button eternally as shown below:

[image: problempreview1]

However, **if the user manually clicked the same MetaMask wallet button** in the same chrome instance, the `Metamask Notification` window would immediately appear as expected, asking the user to log in for then connecting the wallet to that site, as shown below:

[image: expected_result1]

I even checked if there was another hidden window handle after pressing the MetaMask wallet button (via automation) with this code, but there was nothing else:

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
            if handle != initial_page:
                login_page = handle
                driver.switch_to.window(login_page)
```

So, I'm confused, why does that button apparently only work when a user presses it but not when a program does? As always, I'd appreciate a lot if someone could explain what's happening and how could I fix this?

Comment: May the website you are trying to automate have detected it as a bot. I executed the code written by you and it worked fine.

Comment: Clicking on **MetaMask** does opens a new tab but there's no login field :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out already, and it was a foolish thing, I simply had to add the extension path (which [must be compressed](https://www.addictivetips.com/web/how-to-export-an-installed-extension-chrome/) as a `.crx` file) as an argument to Selenium's `Options()`, here's the improved code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data') #Add the user data path as an argument in selenium Options
opt.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default") #Add the profile directory as an argument in selenium Options
extension_path = r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn\10.8.1_0.crx' #assign the extension path of the compressed Metamask extension to this variable
opt.add_extension(extension_path) #add the extension_path as argument

s = Service(r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\chromedriver.exe') #Use the chrome driver located at the corresponding path  

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) #execute the chromedriver.exe with the previous conditions
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://opensea.io/') #go to the opensea main page.

initial_page = driver.current_window_handle  #make the previous page the current one
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button'))) #wait for the wallet button to be enabled for clicking
wallet_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/div[2]/li/button')
wallet_button.click() #click that wallet button
#time.sleep(1)
wallet_options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-testid='WalletSidebar--body']//li")
for i in wallet_options:
    if "MetaMask" in i.get_attribute('innerText'): #find the MetaMask wallet button
        i.click() #click the MetaMask wallet button
```

So when you compile the enhanced code, it generates the following output:

[image: solution1]

Something I noticed was that this program ended up opening **a chromedriver tab** and **a new window** to access the Metamask wallet (ie **both things are used for the same thing**).

If anyone figures out **how to prevent the MetaMask tab from opening as shown in the image**, please let me know in the comments.